# Python text to speech library download problem

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I am tying to install the library pyttsx3 by running `pip install pyttsx3` But it gives my this output:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyttsx3
  Downloading pyttsx3-2.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyttsx3/setup.py) egg_info for package pyttsx3
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'summary'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyttsx3/setup.py:12: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: Parameters to load are deprecated.  Call .resolve and .require separately.
      The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
Downloading/unpacking pyobjc>=2.4 (from pyttsx3)
  Downloading pyobjc-7.0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyobjc/setup.py) egg_info for package pyobjc
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyobjc/setup.py", line 536
        print(f"Framework {fwk} not in framework-wrappers.rst")
                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyobjc/setup.py", line 536

    print(f"Framework {fwk} not in framework-wrappers.rst")

                                                         ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_username/pyobjc
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/tmp7QzgEE
```

What should I do?

BTW I am using Visual Studio Code. a--------------------------------------------------
Stackoverflow doesn't give me the access to post this question because it is mostly code so I am writing this. Please do not care.

Comment: The library uses Python 3.6+ f-string syntax. It won't run in Python 2.7, which is outdated BTW.

Comment: I just downloaded the 3.7 but It seems that in the python folder inside library (Mac) there is not 3.7, how can I put there

Comment: Because I think that is why I cannot download the library to 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem,
The library that I wanted to download wasn't compatible with python2.7. When I passed into 3.9, it worked.